# Noisy sorter: optimal algorithm

Tags: sorting, probabilistic-algorithms

Given $n$ elements $x_1,\dots, x_n$, and algorithm $A$ which outputs $(r_1,\dots, r_n)=A(x_1,\dots, x_n)$, we say $A$ is $\epsilon$-sorting the list if $rank(x_i) \in (r_i-n\epsilon, r_i+ n\epsilon) $ for all $i$, where $rank(x_i)$ is the exact rank of $x_i$: $rank(x_i):=\#\{j:x_j\le x_i\}$.

Suppose we have a noisy comparator that with $p+1/2$ probability will give the right order between two elements. What's the optimal number of calls to the noisy comparator in order to $\epsilon$-sort a list with probability $1-\delta$?

**Algorithm 1** One way to reduce the problem to normal sorting is by amplifying the comparison by using the comparator multiple times and taking the majority vote on it. If we apply it $k$ times the probability of failure will decrease as $\exp(-k/p^2)$. So with $k = \Omega(p^{-2}\log\frac{1}{\delta}\log n)$  and applying any $n\log n$ sorting on top will lead to a sorted list with $1-\delta$ probability.  This would imply a $O(p^{-2}\log\frac{1}{\delta}n\log(n)^2)$ for $\epsilon = 1/n$.

**Algorithm 2** Let us assume we are applying quicksort with random pivot. Then with high probability after $O(\log(1/\epsilon))$ recursive levels all partitions are of $n\epsilon$ size, and if all majority votes so far is correct, the ranks must be correct up to $n\epsilon$ indices. This can be ensured with $O(p^{-2}\log\frac{1}{\delta}\log\frac{1}{\epsilon}n\log n)$ calls to the noisy comparator.

My main questions are:

- Is the query complexity of algorithm 2 optimal in $\delta$ and $\epsilon$?
- Can we avoid asking a fixed pair multiple times? Namely, can we constraint the algorithm to query each pair at most $O(1)$ times?

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1191.

Comment: I don't understand Algorithm 2.  Can you explain what you mean by "applying the sorting algorithm until the end" and by "sub-problems"?  Which sorting algorithm, and what are the sub-problems?  Are you thinking of something like MergeSort?  What do you do on the subproblems of size $n\epsilon$?

Comment: I'm looking at the following type of algorithm: for $i:=1,2,\dots,\lg n$, for $j:=1,2,\dots,n$, compare $x_j$ to $\alpha$ randomly chosen other elements whose estimated rank is in $[\text{est.rank}(x_j)-n/2^i,\text{est.rank}(x_j)-n/2^i]$, count the fraction $r$ that $x_j$ is larger than, then update the estimated rank of $x_j$ to $\text{est.rank}(x_j)+[(r-p+1/2)/(p+1/2) - 1]n/2^i$.  I suspect it might suffice to take $\alpha$ to be $O(p^{-2}f(\delta))$ for some function $f$.  If this worked, it would lead to an algorithm with running time $O(p^{-2} f(\delta) n \log n)$.

Comment: You're right it's not "any" sorting algorithm. Here I meant any sorting algorithm that partitions the list recursively, and by sub-problems I refer to the size of this partitions. I updated to clarity the question

Comment: interesting idea, so you're sorting elements locally and then globally. I was so far trying to do the opposite by using something like quick sort